# Clojure FileNotFound exception when running uberjar, though file is in project source

Tags: clojure, compilation, namespaces

I am pulling my hair out trying to resolve the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate composer/midi/short_message__init.class or composer/midi/short_message.clj on classpath: , compiling:(events.clj:12:1)
```

The reference to `short-message` is in the namespace declaration of `events.clj`:

```
(ns composer.ui.events
  (:use [seesaw core border chooser])
  (:require [composer.midi
             [io :as io]
             [time :as time]
             [player :as player]
             [short-message :as short]]))
```

And here is the namespace declaration of `short-message` itself in `short-message.clj`:

```
(ns composer.midi.short-message
  (:require [composer.algorithm.transform :refer :all]
            [composer.algorithm.markov.transform :refer :all]
            [composer.midi [io :refer :all] [message :as message]]))
```

`short-message` is in the same directory as all other files in `composer.midi`, and yet this seems to be the only one that is resulting in an issue. Indeed, after verifying the `target` directory in my project, this is the only namespace which doesn't seem to contain a corresponding class file. I thought it could be an error with the code, but if I try to load the file with `(load-file "src/composer/midi/short-message.clj")` at the REPL I don't have any issues.

Comment: Hrm. It appears that `short-message.clj` is not a valid filename. Changing it to `short_message` appears to have done the trick... very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is right. In clojure dashes in namespaces correspond to underscore in filenames. So your file name should be short_message.clj as you found.